# How to resolve Openssl Package error while installing nginx

Tags: rhel, yum, openssl, nginx

I tried to install nginx in a **RHEL 7.2 machine**, and i got an error,

```
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.2-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Nut this libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) is not available on default openssl package so i removed the current openssl package and installed using rpm as below,

```
[root@db-brm ~]# rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I thought it would solve the issue but it did not and it increase the conflict in openssl and giving error while installing nginx,

I could see this is the error,

```
[root@db-brm ~]# yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You 
can use subscription-manager to register.
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                       
|  16 kB  00:00:00     
local-repo                                                                                                                                                 
| 4.1 kB  00:00:00     
nginx                                                                                                                                                      
| 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1.0.2 for package: 1:nginx-1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (local-repo)
       Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
       Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 (installed)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-8.el7
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (local-repo)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

***Can anyone help me to solve this issue?***

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there are some problems with last nginx version. In my case `yum install nginx-1.12.1` helped

Comment: Thanks this worked for me . Even 1.12.2 does not work .

Answer (score 0):

run  `yum --showduplicates list nginx`

try to install some other nginx version

for me `yum install nginx-1.10.1-1.el7` works